# Is there any way to search for accented characters in SSRS report viewer?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014, reportserver, accent-insensitive

I am generating a report through SSRS 2014 in which there is a column for location . Some locations have accented characters in their name , which do not appear while searching. In this example Ōtara word can not searched by typing Otara in the search box . Is it possible to do so?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ensure you are using an Accent Insensitive Collation and then `N'Ōtara'` and `N'Otara'` will be treated as having equal values.

Comment: Are you talking about the stored procedure that returns the data for this report?

Comment: No, I'm talking about the data in your database.

Comment: Regarding collation, this article may be a start: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-collation-introduction-with-collate-sql-casting/

Comment: What exactly does "can not be searched by typing" mean? Is this an issue without the SSRS GUI with a dropdown list (or similar control)? Is this an issue with using the value in your image (<frowny face>) as a parameter to the query that generates your report?

Comment: I mean by typing in search box in the toolbar off SSRS report view , I have attached a picture for reference

Comment: I think the problem is with the Report control itself. Even if the column has the correct collation, it appears the search function of the control is only searching the output rather than the underlying data (which makes sense). If the collation is accent insensitive and you passed "Otara" as a parameter value to be used in a where clause of your dataset query  then it would return the value as you expect, but the report control search would still not find it.

Comment: @Alan Schofield If I implemented my own custom find control for SSRS report viewer , will it be possible?

Comment: That's not something I can answer I'm afraid. I suggest you start a new question focusing on that.